# Why List class has to contain a Node struct as a private member C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, computer-science

The implementation of Linked List in Mark Weiss's data structure book confuses me a little.

The List class contains a Node struct inside as follows.

```
...
class List {
    private:
        struct Node {
            ...
        };
    ... 

    public:
        ...

    private:
        int theSize;
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
};
```

My question is that is having a Node struct inside the List class really necessary? I think as long as the List class contains pointer to the header and tail node is enough. What is the advantage of having a Node struct as a private member?

Thanks!

Comment: Well the Node type has to be defined somewhere. Are you asking why it is defined as a private type inside List instead of elsewhere?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. `Node` is an "inner struct", a struct defined inside of another struct. There is *not* a private `Node` member.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you think the Node definition is not needed any where?  IMHO, at least a forward declaration must exist prior to (and visible to) the List class.  See also pimple idiom.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I know that Node has to be declared somewhere. When I implemented the Linked List, I declared it outside of the linked list class. The only data I put inside the linked list is the two pointers header and trailer. I was just wondering what is the advantage of declaring Node struct inside linked list over outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that the Node structure would be declared as a private declaration within the List class is to keep it private to the implementation. This will ensure that the specific details of the implementation do not leak into the public interface. This is an effective way to abstract the interface from the internal implementation details, leaving those details free to change without impacting users of the List classes public interface.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! But is there a difference between declare Node inside the linked list vs outside linked list?

Comment: You are welcome. The difference is that when it is declare private inside the linked list no code outside of the list can use the Node class, it is totally private to the list implementation. If it was declare outside of the list class then other code could also access the class. If a class is not designed to be reused, ie. it is specialized and not designed for general use it is good practice to keep that private. HTH

Comment: This also allows the list class to enforce constraints on the structure without the code outside being able to bypass those constraints because they happen to have access to the node structure and can manipulate the Next/Prev pointers directly for example. Of course this should not be confused with a security mechanism, if the caller really wanted to he/she could still do bad things, but at least this design tries to guide them to the right path and indicate that this should not be messed with and the compiler will help enforce that as far as possible.

Comment: That makes so much sense now! Thanks again! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that is having a Node struct inside the List class really necessary?

It's not necessary but it is better.

1. `List::Node` can be different from `Set::Node`, which can be different from `DList::Node`, which can be different from `Map::Node`. Having a `Node` class outside of `List` that is useful only for implementing `List` does not make sense. You'll have to create `ListNode`, `SetNode`, etc. to make them distinct types.
2. Having `Node` as a nested class makes sure that the details of the class are specific to `List`.
3. It does not pollute the global namespace with type names that are not useful outside the implementation of `List`.
4. It allows `Node` to be `private` to `List`. The details of `Node` are not exposed to users of `List` unless the implementation of `List` chooses to. In most cases, it is not exposed.